# firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

After several attempts using `useRef`, `useEffect` and reading document I can't seem mount recaptcha correctly and utilize signInWithPhoneNumber().

Followed this web guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

firebaseConfig.js

```
import fb from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

var config = {...};

// Initialize Firebase
export const firebase = fb.initializeApp(config);
```

Signup.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { firebase } from "./firebaseConfig";

const Signup = () => {
  const captchaRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      "recaptcha-container",
      {
        size: "invisible",
        callback: function (response) {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          onFinish();
        },
      }
    );
  });

  const onFinish = ({ mobile }) => {
    var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(mobile, appVerifier)
      .then(function (confirmationResult) {
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        var verificationCode = window.prompt(
          "Please enter the verification " +
            "code that was sent to your mobile device."
        );

        confirmationResult
          .confirm(verificationCode)
          .then(function (result) {
            // User signed in successfully.
            var user = result.user;
            // ...
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // User couldn't sign in (bad verification code?)
            // ...
          });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        // ...
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="recaptcha-container"> </div> <Form onFinish={onFinish} />{" "}
      <Button id="submit" htmlType="submit">
        Send
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo, drop the parenthesis of `firebase.auth()` on `new firebase.auth().RecaptchaVerifier(`. `RecaptchaVerifier` is an attribute of `firebase.auth` not `firebase.auth()`, so you have to construct it this way:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(...);
```

*Note that you should replace the three dots with the arguments.*

**EDIT**

Also, you have to change `firebase` to `fb` since you want the Firebase library namespace, not the Firebase application instance, e.g.:

```
import fb from "firebase/app";

// ...

window.recaptchaVerifier = new fb.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(...);
```

Remember to import firebase again or to export it from firebaseConfig.js .

Comment: Thanks for your input but I changed it to that due to the error being output: _services_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_20__.firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a constructor

Comment: My bad, I always import Firebase as `firebase` so I didn't think twice about the name. But, you imported it as `fb` and `firebase` is the app instance so you need to use them as such. I've updated my answer, check if it works now :).

Comment: I understand but what should my new import look like since I deconstructed it? how do I exort fb out of my config? import { firebase, fb? } from "./firebaseConfig";

Comment: I think the cleaner way is to use `import fb from "firebase/app";` again on this file.

Comment: Yeah, I did that was thinking of keeping everything in my firebaseConfig but it is working now thank you!